# Error debido a que mi conexión no es segura

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo un problema cuando ejecuto un programa que haya creado con Laravel: Me salta que mi conexión no es segura.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora esto no me habia dado ningun problema, pero actualmente me quiero conectar a sitios como Facebook y Hitbut y ahi me da error debido a esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como arreglo mi configuración para que sea segura? Me sale de codigo de error "SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER".

Más detalles: Para crear el proyecto use un programa llamado Laragon, el cual permite fabricar el programa y entrar en el mediante un host virtual, el cual lo tengo como "{name}.local". Si mi proyecto se llama learning, tengo que escribir en el URL "learning.local".

Una vez que lo escribo, al ver el URL lo tengo como "http://learning.local/". Si cambio a "https://learning.local/", sale un mensaje de error debido a conexión insegura.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿qué tipo de servidor utilizas? Deberías usar homestead.

Comment: Creo que es [secure_asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-secure-asset) lo que estas buscando.

Comment: No @J.Rodríguez, está hablando de hacer un login con Facebook, no de buscar assets.

Comment: @Shaz ok, comprendo

Comment: He editado mi pregunta para añadir más información.